# jQuery in WordPress Plugin

Tags: plugin-development, jquery

I am learning WordPress plugin development. Now I need to place jQuery code in one file. Where can I place jQuery code ?

Comment: Have you double-checked to make sure jQuery isn't already running wherever you need it? Most themes include it on the front end, and it's typically also included on the back end. Where are you trying to include it?

Comment: Thanks @WebElaine. I would like to export a JavaScript file with my plugin as ZIP format. Where can I place the javascript file ? Thanks.

Comment: @WebElaine I don't believe the OP knows how to create a javascript file and load it in the browser via a plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should place the `.js` file into your plugin directory (it can be root or any other folder like `assets` or `js`).

#### To enqueue JS and CSS files in the front-end:

```
function wp_357866_enqueue_frontend()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('your-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/path/to/js/your-script.js', array(), null, true); // You should set the last parameter to 'true' to load JS in the footer
    wp_enqueue_style('your-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/path/to/css/your-style.css', array(), null);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_357866_enqueue_frontend' );
```

Reference: [wp_enqueue_scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/)

#### To enqueue JS and CSS in the administration:

```
function wp_357866_enqueue_admin()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('your-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/path/to/js/your-script.js', array(), null, true); // You should set the last parameter to 'true' to load JS in the footer
    wp_enqueue_style('your-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/path/to/css/your-style.css', array(), null);
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wp_357866_enqueue_admin' );
```

Reference: [admin_enqueue_scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_enqueue_scripts/)

Comment: Thanks @Cadu De Castro Alves, How to use `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook ? Some sample code is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You should place your javascript inside a `.js` file in your plugin, then enqueue it using the `wp_enqueue_script` function on the appropriate hook. Be sure to declare `jquery` as a dependency when you call `wp_enqueue_script`, and be sure to call it on the correct hook or WordPress will complain